# Adding select to joomla page editor

Tags: joomla

I'm currently working on a Joomla 3.5 site. I am experienced with PHP and Javascript but never worked with Joomla before. So I know how to code.

I want to add a select list to the page editor of Joomla, and when the user makes a selection I want a custom HTML fragment pasted to the page.
The items for the select comes from a database.

Can someone point explain how I can do this?

PS, I am not looking for a plugin, I want to write my own!

I tried this tutorial already: https://tushev.org/web/joomla-articles-and-tutorials/21, But it doesn't add the button to the edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found a solution. It's really easy.
In plugins/editors-xtd/readmore you can see how it can be achieved.
It's a complete and working example.
You can copy the code and modify it.